# How to project 3d vertex to 2d vertex in JavaScript using 2d canvas?

Tags: javascript, 3d, html5-canvas, 2d, projection

I have a camera class that is supposed to project a 3d point to 2d, but I don't know how to properly calculate the perspective projection for the 3d point. I've tried dividing x and y by z, but I don't think it is the correct formula for perspective projection.

I am using a form of the left handed coordinate system. (Illustrated below)

[image]

(X is left and right, Y is up and down, and Z is forward and backward.)

Here is all of the code:

```js
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

function random(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function clamp(min, max, value) {
  if (value < min) {
    value = min;
  } else if (value > max) {
    value = max;
  }

  return value;
}

class Camera {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, fov = 60, rotation = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0
  }, zNear = 0.1, zFar = 1000) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.fov = fov;
    this.rotation = rotation;
    this.zNear = zNear;
    this.zFar = zFar;
  }

  project3dPointTo2d(point) {
    // Fix these calculations
    return {
      x: point.x / point.z,
      y: point.y / point.z
    }
  }
}


/**
 * @type { HTMLCanvasElement }
 */
var scene = document.getElementById("scene");
var ctx = scene.getContext("2d");

var vWidth = window.innerWidth;
var vHeight = window.innerHeight;

var fps = 60;
var updateLoop;

var keysDown = [];

function resizeCanvas() {
  vWidth = window.innerWidth;
  vHeight = window.innerHeight;
  scene.width = vWidth;
  scene.height = vHeight;
}

resizeCanvas();

var testcamera = new Camera(0, 0, -10, 60, {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  z: 0
}, 0.1, 1000);

var testpoint = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  z: 100
}

function main() {
  // Logic
  if (keysDown["w"]) {
    testcamera.z++;
  }

  if (keysDown["s"]) {
    testcamera.z--;
  }

  if (keysDown["a"]) {
    testcamera.x--;
  }

  if (keysDown["d"]) {
    testcamera.x++;
  }

  var proj2dPoint = testcamera.project3dPointTo2d(testpoint);

  // Drawing
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, vWidth, vHeight);

  ctx.save();

  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(proj2dPoint.x, proj2dPoint.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.restore();
}

window.onload = function() {
  updateLoop = setInterval(main, 1000 / fps);
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  keysDown[e.key] = true;
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  keysDown[e.key] = false;
});

window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
  resizeCanvas();
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  font-family: roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, system-ui;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="scene"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

(You can see the point is in the top left instead of the center of the screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the reason your *projected* point is at the top-left of the screen is simply that the origin `(x=0 ; y=0)` of the underlying canvas' coordinate system **is** at the top-left. If you want something to be centered, you have to either move the origin to another position or just translate each point by a constant value e.g. half the canvas's width for a horizontal translation.

This can be done inside your `project3dPointTo2d` method before returning the projected point.

Second, for a simple perspective projection you usually scale the projected points by a given factor, so that points further from the screen plane appear to be closer together. In you code this would be controlled by the `fov` variable and a point's `z` value. Unfortunately your calculation is incomplete.

Lastly, to see that your projection is working you of course need more than one point. A good start is always a simple cube made of 8 points.

Here's an example based on your code:

```js
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

function random(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function clamp(min, max, value) {
    if (value < min) {
        value = min;
    } else if (value > max) {
        value = max;
    }

    return value;
}

class Camera {
    constructor(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, fov = 60, rotation = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0
    }, zNear = 0.1, zFar = 1000) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.fov = fov;
        this.rotation = rotation;
        this.zNear = zNear;
        this.zFar = zFar;
    }

    project3dPointTo2d(point) {
        let scale = this.fov / (this.fov + point.z);

        return {
            x: point.x * scale + vWidth / 2,
            y: point.y * scale + vHeight / 2
        }
    }
}


/**
 * @type { HTMLCanvasElement }
 */
var scene = document.getElementById("scene");
var ctx = scene.getContext("2d");

var vWidth = window.innerWidth;
var vHeight = window.innerHeight;

var fps = 60;
var updateLoop;

var keysDown = [];

function resizeCanvas() {
    vWidth = window.innerWidth;
    vHeight = window.innerHeight;
    scene.width = vWidth;
    scene.height = vHeight;
}

resizeCanvas();

var testcamera = new Camera(0, 0, -10, 60, {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0
}, 0.1, 1000);



let points = [{
        x: -50,
        y: -50,
        z: 0
    },
    {
        x: 50,
        y: -50,
        z: 0
    },
    {
        x: -50,
        y: 50,
        z: 0
    },
    {
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        z: 0
    },
    {
        x: -50,
        y: -50,
        z: 50
    },
    {
        x: 50,
        y: -50,
        z: 50
    },
    {
        x: -50,
        y: 50,
        z: 50
    },
    {
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        z: 50
    }
];

function main() {
    // Logic

    if (keysDown["w"]) {
        testcamera.z++;
    }

    if (keysDown["s"]) {
        testcamera.z--;
    }

    if (keysDown["a"]) {
        testcamera.x--;
    }

    if (keysDown["d"]) {
        testcamera.x++;
    }

    let proj2dPoint;

    // Drawing
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, vWidth, vHeight);

    ctx.save();

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    points.forEach(point => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        proj2dPoint = testcamera.project3dPointTo2d(point);
        ctx.arc(proj2dPoint.x, proj2dPoint.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    });
    ctx.restore();
}

window.onload = function() {
    updateLoop = setInterval(main, 1000 / fps);
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    keysDown[e.key] = true;
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    keysDown[e.key] = false;
});

window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
    resizeCanvas();
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  font-family: roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, system-ui;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="scene"></canvas>
```